# showModalBottomSheet stacking when using a Switch

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm trying to show a privacy policy banner on the login screen of my app.
Whenever I click the switch another ModalBottomSheet stacks on top of the other one though.

I've tried to extract the button in an seperated Statefullwidget no change.

Any suggestions, hints or ideas?

`````
    var setting = Provider.of<SettingProvider>(context);
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      if (setting.data == false) {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            barrierColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.1),
            isDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 0),
                height: 300,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Datenschutz',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Caveat',
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Description.',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    ),
                    SwitchListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'I agree.',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                        value: setting.initdata,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setting.changeInitData(value);
                        }),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (setting.initdata == true) {
                            setting.changeData(setting.initdata);
                            Navigator.pop(context, 'Sichern');
                          } else {
                            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                msg:
                                    'Error.',
                                gravity: ToastGravity.TOP);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Sichern')),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    });````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one way to solve it. Might not be the most elegant way but it works.

In the button to save privacy settings I used `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LogInScreen.routeName);` instead of `Navigator.pop`.

The modals are still stacking when pressing the `Switch`, but the user doesn't have to click through multiple modals..